# how to allow people to tag my business page

Tags: facebook, tags

I have a Facebook business page, and I'm told that when people try and tag it in pictures, it does not show up. I've checked the "People can tag photos posted by *busniess name*" in the manage permissions section of the page, and they have liked my page, but it still does not show up.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?